# EditText textAllCaps not working with textIsSelectable

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a TextView in my layout:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:text="Hello"
    />
```

textAllCaps works good, no problem. But when I try to make text selectable by adding textIsSelectable

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:text="Hello"
    />
```

textAllCaps not working. It seems like these two attributes can't work together properly. Have you any suggestions why it happens and how to make text both all caps and selectable (I'm interested in a most clear way, not setting text change listener and capitalizing text manually). I'll be appreciate for any suggestions, thank you.

Comment: `setFocusableInTouchMode(true);` && `setFocusable(true);`

Comment: you can go with @Logic answer it work for me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one solution. It's to use **AppCompatTextView** and **app:textAllCaps**:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:text="Hello"
    />
```

I'm not sure this is the best solution (AppCompatTextView [docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatTextView.html) tells to use this component only when creating custom components), but it works.

Answer (score 7):

Can you try this in `Activity` :

`edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.AllCaps()});`

Answer (score 0):

You can set inputType property as "textCapCharacters" for Uppercase keyboard as default

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use like this

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:id="@+id/input_postcode"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"  //use this line dont forgot
                            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/et_postcode"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:hint="Post code "
                                android:inputType="text" //dont use hereinputtype
                                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                                android:maxLength="4"
                                android:padding="10dp"
                                android:textAllCaps="true"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="15sp" />
                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```